# Only the first character of random id is inserted to the sql table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database, sql-function, database-trigger

I am doing a bulk insert into a table. i have multiple triggers to insert several columns from the bulk insert to different tables. i generate alphanumeric characters of length 25 as id. I created a function to do this, calling this function where i need values for @ID columns. but i get only the first digit of those random string's characters inserted.

*Trigger where i call my function*

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CHEMICAL WHERE Chemical_Name = @Chemical_Name)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO CHEMICAL(Chemical_ID, Chemical_Name, CAS_Number,EHS,TPQ_Pounds,RQ_Pounds,last_updated)
        VALUES(dbo.SDS_GENERATE_ID(), @Chemical_Name,@CAS_Number, @EHS,@TPQ_Pounds,@RQ_Pounds,getdate())
    END
```

*Function SDS_GENERATE_ID*

```
CREATE FUNCTION SDS_GENERATE_ID()
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @r varchar(25)
SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') + n
FROM (SELECT top 25 
CHAR(number) n FROM
master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P' AND 
(number between ascii(0) and ascii(9)
or number between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
or number between ascii('a') and ascii('z'))
ORDER BY (select * from MyRAND)) a
return @r
   END;
   GO
```

**MyRand VIEW SINCE I CANT USE NEWID() in udfs**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyRAND]
AS
select newid() as randID
GO
```

[image: The Chemical_ID column suppose to have 25 char long id]

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: "Only one character..." almost always means you've declared a varchar without specifying a length somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION SDS_GENERATE_ID()
RETURNS VARCHAR
```

You will need to specify  length,otherwise you will end up receiving single Char

your function at its current form returns only below value..

```
0
```

when modified by specifying length like below returns

```
CREATE FUNCTION SDS_GENERATE_ID()
RETURNS VARCHAR(25)
```

gives

```
01234656789..
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't **specified character length** in function return type:

```
alter FUNCTION SDS_GENERATE_ID()
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @r varchar(25)
SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') + n
FROM (SELECT top 25 
CHAR(number) n FROM
master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P' AND 
(number between ascii(0) and ascii(9)
or number between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
or number between ascii('a') and ascii('z'))
ORDER BY (select id from employee)) a
return @r
   END;
   GO
```

**Note :** replace your required length in above return type